# SQL server 2008 stored procedure environment variable

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, variables, stored-procedures

I have a number of tables in two test databases. The 1st database is current and the 2nd is a snapshot from a year ago.
I have a few stored procs hang off the 1st db which also reference the 2nd.

My question is, what method should I use so that I don't have to modify my stored procs when I move to production.

If this were a coding problem, I would use environment variables. What are my options with sql server 2008.

Thank you.

Comment: "what method should I use" - standard change control...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand your question, some more details would help.

Probably your stored procedures should not be tied to a particular database, should they? 
If not I'd advise to remove references to the specific databases.

We use in our company multi-database stored procedures & triggers. Depending on the production systems the database names can change. 
When we install or upgrade the databases, we use DB-agnostic SQL installation scripts, the databases are identified as specific variable keywords, then we use sed-like scripting that find & replace the database names variable keywords by the actual database names within the T-SQL, then we apply the DB-specific T-SQL script. It's simple, fast, and portable to any production database, the T-SQL without replacing the keywords is not valid (so I can;t be executed without replacing the DB names keywords).

But this is a very special case, and I rarely hear about cross database stored procedures, it complicates quite a lot the system and the management of privileges.

I don't see the point in using environment variables, that could be overwhelming and you'd have to build your requests as strings before executing them which is not recommended. And you'd have to rewrite your stored procedures for proceeding this way in any case.

This is my first answer attempt on Stack Overflow. I hope this answer helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Loic, I'll look into scripting the migration.  You've probably guessed I'm quite new to this.  How do I create stored procs that are not tied to a DB?

Comment: A strored procedure does not require to contain the name of the database. To setup the procedure you just have to execute the T-SQL onto the database you want the procedure on. The database is optionally specified prior to the "CREATE PROCEDURE" block (that defines the stored procedure) by a USE statement followed by a GO statement. If database USE statement is omitted your stored procedure is created on the database you are currently connected to.